# bootstrap modal should have selected table row obtained from json (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table and using ng-repeat data is populated, which is obtained from JSON

Table has name, phone and time

when i click on name a bootstrap modal pops up, but i need to have selected name inside bootstrap modal

```
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat='row in rows'>
            <td data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" ng-modal="" > <a>{{row.name}}</a></td>

                 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-body">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">{{row.name}} Details</h4>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <td>{{ row.phone}}</td>
            <td>{{row.time}} </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/JX1hxzknZ0YIJKnzSGaf?p=preview

I want table's clicked name to be on modal heading

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an ng-click handler that sets the name to a scope property. Then use this property to be the title of the modal heading.

In your HTML that generates the table:

```
ng-click="setName(row.name)"
```

In your controller:
    $scope.selectedName = null;

```
$scope.setName = function(name) {
  $scope.selectedName = name;
}
```

Then you would use this for your modal header

```
{{selectedName}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please implement it in plunker. This could be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to add a function in the controller that sets the name to a current scope variable and then display that variable in the header.
Please find the link for a modified plunker.

[modified plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ss0TrpGdfrokPCrZqqqX?p=preview)

script.js:

```
$scope.getName = function(name) {
     $scope.fName = name;}
```

home.html

```
<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">{{fName}}</h4>
```

Hope it helps.